# Solution to the heat equation using a finite difference scheme

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, finite-differences, heat-equation

I have used a difference scheme and Fourier Analysis to find an expression for the solution to the heat Equation. My problem is plotting my solution.

$w_{k,j,m}=(1-\Delta t\mu_k)^msin(k\pi x_j)$

$\mu_k=\frac{4}{(\Delta x)^2}sin^2(k\pi \Delta x/2)$

$X_{k,j}=sin(k\pi x_j) , j=1,...n$

$v=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\gamma_kw_k$

The coefficients ${\gamma_k}$ are ditermined by using the initial condition: $v_{j,0}$ (meaning $t=0$) for $j=1,...,n.$
Since $w_k=X_k$ at $t=0$, we want to determine ${\gamma_k}$ such that : $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\gamma_k X_{k,j}=f(x_j)$ for $j=1,...,n$.

To get to the equation below, there are some more equations that needs to be listed:

$g=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k v_k$ where $c_1,c_2,...c_n$ are real coefficients. 
It is also given that:
$<g,v_m>_h=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k<v_k,v_m>_h=\frac{c_m}{2}$
Where $<g,v_m>_h$ is the discrete inner Product of g and $v_m$.
Since $v_k=sin(k\pi x_j)$, $g$ can be expressed in the following way:
$g(x_j)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n2<g,v_k>_hsin(k\pi x_j), j=1,...,n$.
From the expressions above, the expression for $\gamma_k$ can be found:

$\gamma_k=2\Delta x\sum\limits_{j=1}^nf(x_j)X_{k,j}$

I am supposed to plot $v$, but I have some problems:
- How can we get a value for $f(x_j)$? In the book it says that $f(x_j)=v_{j,0}$,meaning t=0. The problem is that v is a function of $\gamma_k$ which again is a function of $f(x_j)$. Does anyone know how to get a value for $ f(x_j)$, without going in an infinite loop?
David

Comment: I've edited as much as I can. Can you check if it's correct?

Comment: It is correct. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to determine $\gamma_k$ to satisfy that relationship to some function $f$? Why would that produce information? If it's proven to work, the proof should provide some semantics for $f$. Why would you know $f$ but not the $\gamma_k$? You may have to form a corollary, where you show there's a way to take what you generate from $f$ and produce $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I am going to plot $v=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\gamma_kw_k$. I do know what w is, but the problem is $\gamma_k$. I do know the expression for it, as it is stated above, but I do not know how to find $f(x_j)$. In the book it only said that the coefficients $\gamma_k$ is found using the initial condition: $v_{j,x=0}$. It did say that: "Since $w_k=X_k$ at $t=0$, we want to determine ${\gamma_k}$ such that : $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\gamma_k X_{k,j}=f(x_j)$ for $j=1,...,n$.", but I do not understand how that gives ut the value for $f(x_j)$. X: Only depend on x.